# Testing the Convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to find if the following product has a finite value for positive values of k $$p=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left ( 1+\frac{k}{1} \right )\cdot \left ( 1+\frac{k}{2} \right ) \cdot \left ( 1+\frac{k}{3} \right )...\cdot\left(1+\frac{k}{n} \right )$$
I take log in both sides by which it changes to
$$\ln p=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\ln \left ( 1+\frac{k}{n} \right )$$
To prove absolute convergence of $p$, I have to take a limiting function such that $$|\ln(1+\frac{k}{N})|<u_{N}(k)$$ where $$\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}u_{N}(k)$$ converges.
I cannot think of a limiting function which satisfies above, any suggestions/other methods to prove the finite value of p would be much appreciated.

(**Context**: p appears in the remainder term for the Taylors expansion of $(1+x)^{-k}$ so p must tend to a finite quantity to establish that the remainder term in the series tends to zero as the number of terms approach infinity)

Comment: As $n\to\infty$, $\ln\left(1+\frac kn\right)\sim\frac kn$

Comment: $p$ — better to index that, methinks — or $p_n$ grows like $n^k$. In the remainder term, you should have a factor $x^n$, and that makes the remainder term tend to $0$ for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have done most of the work but your aim is unachievable.  Perhaps you have the wrong expression for the error term (should there be an $x^n$ term as well)?  To see this, for $n > k$, use the power series expansion for $\log(1+x)$ to conclude,
$$\log\left(1+\frac{k}{n}\right) > \frac{k}{n} - \frac{k^2}{2n^2},$$ which means that
$$\sum_{n > k}^{N} \log\left(1+\frac{n}{k}\right) > \sum_{n=k+1}^N \frac{k}{n} - \sum_{n=k+1}^N\frac{k^2}{2n^2}.$$
The second sum on the right converges while the first sum diverges, so the sum on the left eventually becomes unbounded and therefore the original product also diverges.

There is a general result along these lines that says, subject to the right conditions on $m_n$, that an infinite product $\prod (1 + m_n) $ converges in the same way as $\sum m_n$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#:%7E:text=the%20infinite%20product&text=The%20product%20is%20said%20to,to%20those%20for%20infinite%20sums.) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Without any $\log$ just elementary calculations give

$$\left ( 1+\frac{k}{1} \right )\cdot \left ( 1+\frac{k}{2} \right ) \cdot \left ( 1+\frac{k}{3} \right )...\cdot\left(1+\frac{k}{n} \right )\geq 1+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac ki= 1+k\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1i\stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\infty$$